# How to set variable back to 0?

Tags: javascript

How do I set a variable back to 0 in javascript? There are two variables - x and y (x is 3 and y is 1 if that helps at all) Variable x and y in my code are supposed to go back to 0. I tried x = 0 and y = 0 but that didn't work, so how do I do this? This is the top javascript code...

```
var y=1
var x=3
function stickAmount()
{
var stickNo = document.getElementById("stickNumber");
stickNo.innerHTML = "Sticks: "+y;
y++ 
}

function rockAmount()
{
var rockNo = document.getElementById("rockNumber");
rockNo.innerHTML = "Rocks: "+x;
x++
}
```

and I have a function with what I've been trying to do...

```
function ten()
{
x = 0;
y = 0;

var elem = document.getElementById("btnOne");
if (elem.innerHTML=="Feel around the cave") elem.innerHTML = "See around the cave";
else elem.innerHTML = "Feel around the cave";
}
```

Comment: back to '0' ... ? When and Why? You're using `N++` and asking how to reset to `0`. Hope you understand what I don't.

Comment: Show us the code that is failing to set the value back to zero. We can't tell you what is wrong if you don't show us the section that is broken!

Comment: You have the correct way to set a variable to 0, so what exactly did not work? it may be something other than the setting to 0 that is actually not working...

Comment: Well I'm putting the x = 0 and y = 0 in a function and I have a button directing to that button

Comment: Show us that function. Show us how you are calling that function. Show us how you are testing the result.

Comment: @zkatx show us that then, preferably with a fiddle ( JSFiddle ) too

Comment: You've edited the question to show the function that sets the variables to zero. Now show us how you are calling it and how you are testing that the values have changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're expecting [data binding / reactive computing](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02). 
Normally you won't see the changes in `#rockNumber` you just change `x`. You need to call `rockNo.innerHTML = "Rocks: "+x;` again after you change `x`.

Comment: Wow, Just something so basicly... I hope you're right :D

Comment: Yey, I'm a mind reader :)